# Running distributed tensorflow on machines with different versions of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In particular I'm interested in what happens if the tensorflow installed on the parameter server is different from the tensorflow installed on the worker. (E.G: different versions of tensorflow). How does distributed tensorflow reconcile potential differences in the execution code between workers and parameter servers?

Comment: TensorFlow assumes all workers are running the same version of the code. Mismatching version may work if you are lucky, but it may also produce some very hard to diagnose failures

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's highly discouraged. Depending on how many versions they differ, in good cases, you get some errors. In base cases, things seemingly run normally but e.g. nothing trains and you'll have a hard time figuring out why....